# Determining joint probability of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be standard Gaussian distributed random variables and $\rho(X, Y) = \alpha$. Then what is $P(X > x \cap Y > y)$.

I have attempted some form of integration from
$P(X > x \cap Y > y)$ $=$ $P(X > x) \cdot P(Y > y | X > x)$ $=$ $P(X > x) \cdot \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated as I feel quite stumped, and a cursory literally review did not turn anything up.

Comment: See these papers and those cited them: 1) https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347670?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents  2) https://www.jstor.org/stable/2238463 3) https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10618600.1992.10477010. The first used the same idea you have stated. Note that for the bivariate case you can compute directly compute the normal integrals using exiting calculators of definite integrals, e.g., see https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a